# Database strategy for synchronization based on changes

Tags: mysql, database, hibernate, synchronization

I have a Spring+Hibernate+MySQL backend that exposes my model (8 different entities) to a desktop client. To keep synchronized, I want the client to regularely ask the server for recent changes. The process may be as follows:

- Point A: The client connects for the
  first time and retrieves all the
  model from the server.
- Point B: The client asks the server
  for all changes since Point A.
- Point C: The client asks the server
  for all changes since Point B.

To retrieve the changes (point B&C) I could create a HQL query that returns all rows in all my tables that have been last modified since my previous retrieval. However I'm afraid this can be a heavy query and degrade my performance if executed oftenly.

For this reason I was considering other alternatives as keeping a separate table with recent updates for a fast access. I have looked to using L2 query cache but it doesn't seem to serve for my purpose.

Does someone know a good strategy for my purpose? My initial thought is to keep control of synchronization and avoid using "automatic" synchronization tools.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can store changes in a queue table. Triggers can populate the queue on insert, update, delete. this preserves the order of the changes like insert, update, update, delete. Empty the queue after download.

Emptying the queue would cause issues if you have multiple clients.... may need to think about a design to handle that case.

there are several designs you can go with, all with trade offs. I have used the queue design before, but it was only copying data to a single destination, not multiple.